# What happens during Commit while using Lucene NRT

Tags: lucene.net, lucene-nrt

We're using Lucene.NET 2.9.2, and would like to move over to the Near Realtime functionality of Lucene.

We get the `IndexReader` from the `IndexWriter` (thus using `NRT`). My understanding is that when using it this way, the IndexReader will also contain search results of those documents that have been added, but not yet commited (we're checking if the `IndexReader` `iscurrent`, and use `reopen` if it's not).

Let's say I've added 50 documents, and decide to `Commit` them to the index, and let's say the documents are big, and commiting takes 5 seconds.

What happens during these 5 seconds if a new search comes in? Will the internal `RAMDirectory` hold on to those 50 documents until the commit is complete? Or will there be a situation that those 50 documents will be lost for 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to search those records still. Your reader still points to the uncommitted version of the index as if you never called commit. Once commit is finished isCurrent will reflect you need a new reader.